# Value Approximation and significance

Tags: real-analysis

I have a function $f(x)$ that has a unique maximum for $x^*$ ($x^*$ is a real number). Let's say I want to use a simple rule of thumb over a period of time to get to the optimal value $x*$ like the following:
$$x_{t}=x_{t-1} +\lambda (x^*- x_{t-1})  $$ 
Using this rule one is getting closer and closer to the optimal value but the steps are getting smaller and smaller. (just like a geometric series)

Is there a general rule (or convention or statement) like the following: When $x_t$ is approximately close to $x^*$ by 95% (just a random guess) I am close enough to the optimal value? Or in other words: When is $x_t$ close enough to the optimal value so I can say that the simple rule of thumb has reached the optimal value?

Maybe you know some scientific papers that deal with this problem, mainly in economics but any other would also be very helpful.

Thank you.

p.s. I'm not sure if this is the right community but I hope it's not totally wrong.

Example: 
Lets say $x^*=1$ and the starting value for $x_t=0.5$. Using the above rule of thumb and depending on the parameter values I get the following adjustment for $x_t$:

$x_t=[0.5; 0.75; 0.85; 0.92; 0.95; 0.97; 0.98; 0.986; 0.99....]$

Now the Question is: When is $x_t$ close enough to $x^*$ so I can say that I have reached the optimal value? I know that in the mathematical sense this is not a really good question because the answer would be "never". But in this case we are talking about simulations and approximations.

Comment: Since the question now basically is "when is my approximation optimal?", the answer is "when it is good enough for your application". It really depends on the accuracy you want to get from the simulation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm really sorry for the confusion and the work you put into your answer. I thought there are some "general rules" when I can say that the approximation can be regarded as "optimal".

Comment: The answer depends on the cost of being suboptimal. If $x$ is the cruising altitude of an aeroplane then the cost could be several 100 gallons of aviation fuel. If $x$ is the number of Xmas cards to buy this year, then the cost is not so much.

Answer (score 0):

You conclude with "But in this case we are talking about simulations and approximations".
For a simulation or approximation (not to be confused with something that is rough or imprecise) to make sense two kind of values need to be produced by whatever algorithm is used: the approximated value of the unknown of the problem at hand and the maximum error that may affect such a approximated value.
Moreover, if you have an algorithm that can estimate such a maximum error and adapts itself in order to reduce such a maximum error, the expected maximum error can be an input of your simulation.

That said, if you think a while on it you can come at the conclusion that you are asking what is the maximum error you must choose.

In this case the comment by P. Siehr is the answer.